# Append text at starting of file

Tags: java, file, csv, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prepend lines to file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537944/prepend-lines-to-file-in-java)

I have a CSV-file which supports UTF-8 encoding.
I want to insert some text in this file at starting point using java. How can I do this?
I don't want to create another file and write that text and then contents of this file into new file.

Comment: Similar question already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537944/prepend-lines-to-file-in-java

Comment: What you want and what is possible are two completely different things.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - always eloquent in the face of my succinctness.

Comment: @Brian: And you say it better, shorter, *and nicer*. And for that reason I'm going to delete my comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Oh I don't know, I liked *your* comment better. I was just being nice .... for once.

Comment: 'Append ... at starting of file' is a contradiction in terms. Strange that in your original post you used the correct terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to create another file and write that text and then contain of existing file into new file. Then copy new file to the old filename replacing it. This has the added advantage that you can choose not to replace until the end.

An alternative for files that fit in memory would be to slurp it into memory and write it out to the same filename.