# Write to file at explicit line in android java

Tags: android, file

I have an html file in android app public directory that is loaded into a `webView` with `loadData()` function. I did not place this html file in directory `/android_assets`because the file needs to be written to at runtime: [why cannot write to /android_assets at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760684/5620779)

I need to write to the file at runtime by inserting some html snippet at a precise location in the file.
My question is: How to write to file at some line?
I have read that it may not be safe: [Prepending to file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2537991/5620779)

Answer (score 1):

Read the file, write a new copy with the additional information, then either delete the old file and rename the new to the old with `File.renameTo` or `Files.move`, or else (perhaps better), update the reference to point to the new file and then delete the old one.

For instance, suppose the file is `snippet.1.html`, and you refer to this filename based on an entry in a database. You could read the file, and write a modified version as `snippet.2.html`. Only after that had succeeded, update the database to refer to `snippet.2.html`. And only after that has succeeded, delete `snippet.1.html`. Repeat as needed for each time you need to update the file.